# A simple if-then statement in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers

I have been trying to generate a graph where two vertices are connected with probability p. Here is what I tried so far,

```
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % size of circle
 \def \radius {2cm}
 \def \margin {8}
 % number of vertices
 \def \n {5}
 % Probability for an edge to show up between vertices
 \def \p {0.5}

 % Drawing the vertices/nodes
 \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  \node[draw, circle] (\s) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {};

 % Drawing the edges
 \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  \foreach \t in {\s,...,\n}
    % Generate and store a random number to the variable \dummynum
    \pgfmathparse{rnd}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dummynum}{\pgfmathresult}
    % If dummynum is less than p, edge is drawn; otherwise nothing happens
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\dummynum pt < \p pt}}{\draw (\t) -- (\s);}{}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The compiler has been unsuccessful in compiling it, giving me an error "Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete".

I am sure that the problem is in the ifthenelse line, but so far I have no clue how to fix it. Can anyone point out the error and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than deal with the `\ifthenelse` macro from the `xifthen` package, I prefer to use \ifdim ...\fi (which the tikz parser recognizes).  There is also the `\pgfmathifthenelse`, but that would require using `"..."` which my editor automatically converts to ``...'' (one of its less useful features).  Also, `\foreach` requires the code executed to be inside a `{...}` group.  Finally, I have no idea what you were trying to do with `\pgfmathsetseed`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 % size of circle
 \def \radius {2cm}
 \def \margin {8}
 % number of vertices
 \def \n {5}
 % Probability for an edge to show up between vertices
 \def \p {0.5}

 % Drawing the vertices/nodes
 \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
  \node[draw, circle] (\s) at ({360/\n * (\s - 1)}:\radius) {};

 % Drawing the edges
 \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}{
  \foreach \t in {\s,...,\n} {
    % Generate and store a random number to the variable \dummynum
    \pgfmathparse{rnd}
    %\let\dummynum=\pgfmathresult
    % If dummynum is less than p, edge is drawn; otherwise nothing happens
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt < \p pt\relax \draw (\t) -- (\s);\fi
  }}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the use of pgfmathsetseed - but thanks for the working example!

Comment: @user31415 you can use `pgfmathsetseed` to always have the same graph from one compilation to the next. Just call `\pgfmathsetseed{31415}` at the beginning, and change the value if you don't like the way your random graph looks.

Comment: PDF seed changes much faster than PGF as it takes the minute. That's why that command is used.